# Css animation does not occur when removing and adding class without setTimeout

Tags: javascript, css, animation

When class .is-animated is added to the .box element it does a simple animation of changing background.
I want it to do this simple animation let's say every 2 seconds. The issue is that if it already has the .is-animated class and i remove and then add it again the animation does not happen except if i put the addition inside a setTimeout function. Why is this happening? Is the use of setTimeout mandatory in such situation?

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tzeldev/9eod20tz/11/)

HTML

```html
<div class="box box_one"></div>
<div class="box box_two"></div>
```

CSS

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.box.is-animated {animation: changebg 1s ease;}

.box_two { margin-left: 50px;}

@keyframes changebg {
  0%   {background: red;}
  75%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
```

JS

```js
var box_one = document.querySelector('.box_one');

setInterval(function() {
    box_one.classList.remove('is-animated');
    box_one.classList.add('is-animated');
}, 2000);

var box_two = document.querySelector('.box_two');

setInterval(function() {
    box_two.classList.remove('is-animated');
    setTimeout(function() {
        box_two.classList.add('is-animated');
    }, 100);
}, 2000);
```

Comment: If you remove the class and add it again within the same JS "cycle", was it ever really removed? (Not as far as CSS can see!)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need js for this, just add "infinite" to the animation property.

As for the question itself, like Niet the Dark Absol pointed out, if you add and remove a class in the same iteration css never computes it, you would need to use a timeout indeed.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: red;
}
.box.is-animated {animation: changebg 2s ease infinite;}

.box_two { margin-left: 50px;}

@keyframes changebg {
  0%   {background: red;}
  50%  {background: green;}
  100% {background: red;}
}
```

```html
<div class="box box_one"></div>
<div class="box box_two is-animated"></div>
```